# How to verify a production website corresponds to a certain github repo commit when a company claims they are the same

Tags: web-applications, open-source

A company makes their website client side open source and claim that
it is exactly equal to a certain version that can be found in a github repo.

I want to verify their production website (client side) exactly matches the source code.

If I can access their github repo and also the production website via my browser, how can I technically check and verify they match?

Answer (score 0):

Depends.

You can not, in anyway, trust that the back end of the website.

if the public files have not been compiled, you can try to download them all, map them into a structure that could be compare to the source you have

If they have been compiled, then you need to run the precise compilation steps on the sources, then arrange both the result and the public file so they can match. This is btw a very tought job as even small difference is setups could result in very different output.

On a side note, checking that the source match a specific commit isn't that much of a big deal, as you can't really check the infrastructure that run the source and that may create side effects (unless you get to audit it, adn even then it's really about what they want to show you)